# How to add your app to notification center?

Tags: iphone, ios, url-scheme, localnotification, notificationcenter

How to add your app to notification center?

I want to create an custom link that will appear in notification center for my app. Like [Quickpick](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quickpick-the-universal-ios/id483079724?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) create shortcuts.

Any advice, link tutorial related with this is well come.

Comment: https://github.com/Burnsoft/Settings-Swipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your app for a URL scheme that the device can handle. (many answers on this already)

I have a similar app in review as per quickpick and it's uses URL schemes and uilocalnotifications to handle the appropriate action.

As I'm still awaiting formal rejection from apple I'll likely open source the notification element for others to use in their private apps. It's really handy to be able to use notification for quick actions.  Especially if running 5.0 as the private settings urls are available.

update Jan 2012 - doesn't look like notifications are going to be allowed on the appstore anytime soon, so I've open sourced my original [App Swipe](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app-swipe/id482494990?mt=8&partnerId=30&siteID=BcMBY/pRbWY) code.
Hope you find it useful.
https://github.com/Burnsoft/Settings-Swipe

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Then handle the `UILocalNotification` in the startup of you app and do the linked action.